# Is there a way to put multiple null bytes in memory using strcpy?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am trying to craft a string that will overflow a buffer and return to a function within the source code. The returnaddress of this function is

> 0x0000000000400db8

My string so far looks like

> $(perl -e 'print "A" x 120 . "\xb8\x0d\x40\x00"')

My issue is that the 00 on the end of that is a null byte and since strcpy terminates with a null byte, I am unable to add more. Is there any way to get more null bytes. In terms of what is in memory, it has the A's as 0x41414141
then it has the address 0x00400db8 then after that is a 0x00007fff (random garbage) and then a 0x00000000 (could i possibly move these to the address before it.

The 0x00007fff needs to be all zeros. Is there any way to do this. I dont know if it helps but as stated above, there is a full 4 bytes of nulls right after it so maybe there is a way to move those if there is no other way to get around strcpy.

Im very new to this all so as much help and advice would be appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution this this ? facing the same issue now :/

Comment: @DhayalanPro nope :(